# How to properly write an array of bytes in Assembly?

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, nasm

I need to write an array of bytes but i don't get it, only `[matrix + 0]` and `[matrix + 1]` is written(what i mean, EAX should be equal to `0301070F`), what i am doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
segment .data
    matrix times 4 db 0

segment .bss

segment .text

  global asm_main

asm_main:
    enter 0,0
    pusha
    mov eax, 0

    mov dword [matrix + 3], 15
    mov dword [matrix], 3
    mov dword [matrix + 1], 1
    mov dword [matrix + 2], 7

    mov ah, [matrix]
    mov al, [matrix + 1]
    rol eax, 16
    mov ah, [matrix + 2]
    mov al, [matrix + 3]

    dump_regs 1

  popa
  mov eax, 0
  leave
  ret
```

and this is the output of `dump_regs 1`:

```
Register Dump # 1
EAX = 03010000 EBX = B774FFF4 ECX = BFF7C924 EDX = BFF7C8B4
ESI = 00000000 EDI = 00000000 EBP = BFF7C868 ESP = BFF7C848
EIP = 080484D8 FLAGS = 0282       SF
```

The caller is a simple `C` program:

```
int main() {
  int ret_status;
  ret_status = asm_main();
  return ret_status;
}
```

Edited:
I found something wrong here, if i execute this code, all is working:

```
    mov dword [matrix], 3
    mov dword [matrix + 1], 1
    mov dword [matrix + 2], 7
    mov dword [matrix + 3], 15
```

but if i execute this, doesn't work:

```
    mov dword [matrix + 3], 15
    mov dword [matrix], 3
    mov dword [matrix + 1], 1
    mov dword [matrix + 2], 7
```

Why?

Comment: Why is `matrix` a single byte? What do you plan on addressing in the data segment beyond the address of `matrix`? Why not `matrix times 8 db 0`?

Comment: Mmm and what is `matrix times 8 db 0`?

Comment: It is the same as `matrix db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` it is a convenient way to create a label of `times n` length.

Comment: Oh nice, sorry i didn't know. But i have the same problem, `EAX = 03010000` and should be `EAX = 0301070F`.

Comment: Hmm. Let me work with it and I'll drop a note back. I'll track down the pcasm asm_io.inc and run it in `gdb` and see what's going on.

Comment: It's been some time, but shouldn't `mov dword [matrix + n], x` rather be `mov byte [matrix + n], x` to avoid that the constant `x` is treated as a 32bit value? Might also avoid some alignment surprises.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, then `word` for '15' or `byte` again for `0xf` if that is the intent.

Comment: Heyy @FrerichRaabe you deleted the useful answer! thank you, it worked!  Can you re-answer this question? could be useful to other people.

Comment: @DiggaDiggaMigga Done, but I think it would be good if somebody would figure out *why* using `byte` instead of `dword` helps (maybe with some ASCII art to show what's going on in memory). I deleted my answer and re-posted it as a comment because it was more of an 'educated guess'.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Would be great!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been some time, but shouldn't

```
  mov dword [matrix], 3
```

rather be something like

```
  mov byte [matrix], 3
```

to avoid that the constant `3` is treated as a 32bit value?